# Magento - Change Product Page Layout for only one Product in the define Layout Section

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

This is for sure a quicky, but nothing i found so far is working.

I would like to set a different product view for a choosen Product only. Not for a category. I tried to add this to the custom layout tab without any luck so far.

I tried any variantions of this:

```
<reference name="product.info">
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/newview.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

But Magento will not read it!

Is there any easy solution to this ? Or maybe how i can get the template added to the layout dropdown in the Design Tab of the Product ? I mean the Tab where you can choose between 1-2 or 3 Columns Layout.

Thank you very much for your help. I am using Magento 1.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

In your `local.xml` file put the following,

```
<layout>
    ...
    <PRODUCT_86>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/newview.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_86>
    ...     
</layout>
```

Here 86 is a product_id. Flush the cache and then check.

Comment: Hi, this does not solve the issue to enter an XML in the Layout Tab on the Product in the Admin Interface.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is quite easy: Make the new File readable by the Webserver.
For what its worth, maybe it helps someone.